# Firebase Facebook Profile Picture (photoURL) showing standard Facebook Profile Picture

Tags: firebase, image, facebook, flutter, profile

I was looking through the Internet for a answer to my question, however, I was not able to find one. Therefore I am reaching out to you guys:

My problem: When I login with Facebook through Firebase (using flutter_facebook_login plugin) I can retrieve every data perfectly, except the photoURL. Whenever I try to show the profile picture in my UI, I end up with the standard profile picture of facebook, not the one the user is currently using. Any Ideas how I can change that? Thanks in advance!

Code I use to show the picture:

```
Image(image: NetworkImage(widget.user.photoUrl)
```

My self coded, Facebook Login Code:

```
class AuthService {
      final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
      Stream<FirebaseUser> get currentUser => _auth.onAuthStateChanged;
      Future<AuthResult> signInWithCredential(AuthCredential credential) =>
          _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
    
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    final authService = AuthService();
    
    Future<FirebaseUser> loginFacebook() async {
      facebookLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
    
      final result =
          await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']);
    
      switch (result.status) {
        case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
          final FacebookAccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken;
          print('''
              Logged in!
              
              Token: ${accessToken.token}
              User id: ${accessToken.userId}
              Expires: ${accessToken.expires}
              Permissions: ${accessToken.permissions}
              Declined permissions: ${accessToken.declinedPermissions}
              ''');
          break;
    
        case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
          print('Login cancelled by the user.');
          break;
    
        case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
          print('Something went wrong with the login process.\n'
              'Here\'s the error Facebook gave us: ${result.errorMessage}');
          break;
      }
    
      // define Userdata
      //final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
      final FacebookAccessToken fbToken = result.accessToken;
      final AuthCredential credential =
          FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: fbToken.token);
      final _result = await authService.signInWithCredential(credential);
    
      print('${_result.user}');
      return _result.user;
    }
```

Comment: Facebook has recently introduced the requirement for those picture URL requests to contain an access token in certain situations, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/